# Replacing consecutive empty sublists with their run-lengths

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, challenge-community

I have a list like this:

```
l={{12}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {70}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
{}, {4}, {}, {}, {10}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {1}, {36}, {}, {}, {}, \
{87}, {60}, {}, {58}, {3, 16}, {}, {56}, {75}, {14, 53}, {}, {30}, {}, {84}, {}, {59}, {35, 45, 68}};
```

I want to substitute the sequences of `{}` with their run-lengths:

```
compact[l]=={{12}, 4, {70}, 11, {4}, 2, {10}, 5, {1}, {36}, 3, \
{87}, {60}, 1, {58}, {3, 16}, 1, {56}, {75}, {14, 
  53}, 1, {30}, 1, {84}, 1, {59}, {35, 45, 68}}
```

Comment: How big are the lists this will be used on?  Can we find other 6 solutions?
Would anybody be willing to work out some benchmarks of the many solutions I hope we will see here?

Comment: `Sequence` functions aren't going to be competitors @rhermans.

Comment: @Syed let the race begin! 

Answer (score 14):

```
l = {{12}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {70}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
{}, {}, {4}, {}, {}, {10}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {1}, {36}, {}, {}, {}, \
{87}, {60}, {}, {58}, {3, 16}, {}, {56}, {75}, {14, 
    53}, {}, {30}, {}, {84}, {}, {59}, {35, 45, 68}};

SequenceReplace[l, k : {{} ..} :> Length@k]
```

> {{12}, 4, {70}, 11, {4}, 2, {10}, 5, {1}, {36}, 3, {87}, {60}, 1, 
> {58}, {3, 16}, 1, {56}, {75}, {14,    53}, 1, {30}, 1, {84}, 1, {59},
> {35, 45, 68}}

Answer (score 12):

You can also use a composition of [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html), [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[compacT]
compacT = Apply[Join] @* ReplaceAll[ x : {{} ..} :> {Length[x]}] @* Split;

compacT @ l
```

> {{12}, 4, {70}, 11, {4}, 2, {10}, 5, {1}, {36}, 3, {87}, {60}, 1, {58}, {3, 16}, 1, {56}, {75}, {14,
> 53}, 1, {30}, 1, {84}, 1, {59}, {35, 45, 68}}

This seems to be faster than `SequenceReplace` for long input lists.

Answer (score 6):

## Split and conquer

Here I exploit the split functions

#### Using [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html), [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (`/@`) and [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html)

```
 compactRH1[l_] := If[ First[#]=={}, Length[#],  Sequence@@# ]& /@ Split[l]
```

#### Using [`SequenceSplit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceSplit.html) and [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

```
     compactRH2[l_] := Flatten[SequenceSplit[l,x:{{} ..}:>Length[x]],1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `SplitBy` and `If`:

```
Join @@ (If[Total @@ # === 0, {Length[#]}, #] & /@ (SplitBy[l, Length]))

(*{{12}, 4, {70}, 11, {4}, 2, {10}, 5, {1}, {36}, 3, {87}, {60}, 1, {58}, 
  {3, 16}, 1, {56}, {75}, {14, 53}, 1, {30}, 1, {84}, 1, {59}, {35, 45, 68}}*)
```

Or in a more compact way using `ReplaceAll`:

```
Join @@ (SplitBy[l, Length] /. {{x : {} ..} :> {Length@{x}}})

(*{{12}, 4, {70}, 11, {4}, 2, {10}, 5, {1}, {36}, 3, {87}, {60}, 1, {58}, 
  {3, 16}, 1, {56}, {75}, {14, 53}, 1, {30}, 1, {84}, 1, {59}, {35, 45, 68}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{12}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {70}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, 
  {}, {}, {4}, {}, {}, {10}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {1}, {36}, {}, {}, 
  {}, {87}, {60}, {}, {58}, {3, 16}, {}, {56}, {75}, {14, 53}, {}, 
  {30}, {}, {84}, {}, {59}, {35, 45, 68}};
```

Using `SequenceCases` and `First` with its second argument

```
SequenceCases[list, {a_, b : {} ...} :> 
  Sequence[a, First[Values @ Counts[{b}], Nothing]]]
```

> {{12}, 4, {70}, 11, {4}, 2, {10}, 5, {1}, {36}, 3, {87}, {60}, 1,
> {58}, {3, 16}, 1, {56}, {75}, {14, 53}, 1, {30}, 1, {84}, 1, {59}, {35, 45, 68}}